# no MainWindow.xib in Xcode 4.2.1 ios empty project

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, xib

I've started to learn IOS programming using Big Nerd Ranch Guide. (SE)
I've downloaded and istalled xcode 4.2.1

Now the first basic code work have this text

```
In the project navigator, find a file named MainWindow.xib. This file contains the interface for your Quiz application. Click on MainWindow.xib to open it in the editor area.
```

But there is no MainWindow.xib

Because There is no more Window based application type when u start the project.
Instead of that I had to choose empty project.

What is the easiest way to get MainWindow.xib in my project and continue with it ?

Cause I've read this blog http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/where-is-mainwindow-xib-in-xcode-4-2/

And I don't like the way it's done. IS there more gentle , normal way of getting MainWindow.xib???

Comment: What don't you like about that post? That is how it used to be constructed?

Comment: Yes. too complex way. Takes the same time as the whole example app.

Comment: Do it once and save it. I'm sure there must be a way of making your own templates or you could just copy and paste the project as a starting point

Comment: Well if there is no other way, then probably I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Snow Leopard (10.6), you can install Xcode 3 and MainWindow.xib gets created with all the templates there.

I also believe many of the example apps from Big Nerd Ranch [are available online](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=172&t=3274).  So you can download the sample apps (which would have MainWindow.xib files), strip out as much as you can and then re-create them.

Hopefully they'll update the Big Nerd Ranch books to incorporate storyboarding and Xcode 4.2 very soon.  Apple has a bad habit of changing things so often that it might not be economical or wise to be completely up to date with the latest changes.